# Change default page names in Bigcartel Theme (Luna)

Tags: html, bigcartel

I would like to change the name  of the "products" page into "artworks".
I changed it manually in the theme layout (Luna), but that doesn't work of course for the main page title displayed on the browser tab. I looked around in theme options but can't find a way. Thanks for your help, Giorgio

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Design > Code > Products Custom Code

Search for:

{% assign page_name = 'Products' %}

Change to:
{% assign page_name = 'Artworks' %}

Your page's header will change to Artworks along with the browser tab.
See my example [here](https://GainsGangInc.com/products) where I have renamed the products page " C A T A L O G "

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. It's weird but on "products custom code" there's assignment of the page name. Searched on all other code pages, nothing.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you might not need to code this bit. Just change the name of the "Products" category to whatever you like.

Go to Design>Code>Products

Don't go into the code - right at the top of the page where the category is titled Products change it to Artworks.